# Login DAO sql statement involving multiple joins

Tags: sql, jsf, authentication, dao

I am trying to create a query that will return through DAO whether the inputted username and password is correct. I'm using java for DAO implementation as well as JSF.

I have the following tables:

```
LOGIN: username (pk)
BUSINESS: username (fk), password
CUSTOMER: username (fk), password
```

What I'm trying to do is create multiple joins so that when a user goes to log in, their stored username defines what type of account they have. By pulling the username, the username is looked for in both the BUSINESS and CUSTOMER and when found, the password is then compared. I tried the following statement:

```
SELECT l.USERNAME 
FROM ITKSTU.BUSINESS b 
JOIN ITKSTU.LOGIN l 
ON l.USERNAME=b.USERNAME                     
JOIN ITKSTU.CUSTOMER c 
ON c.USERNAME=l.USERNAME
WHERE l.USERNAME='user111' AND (b.PASSWORD='aaa' OR c.PASSWORD='aaa');
```

Yet it returns nothing. Any possible suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated the same here and it looks like it is working. Could you check?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f253d/2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you need is to distinguish a user's type, whether he/she is in business table or customer table. Then, check the password correctness.

Then, again if I am not wrong, you should have an entry for all users in login table, then each one of them should take place EITHER in businees OR customer table.

Let's assume we have records such as:

```
INSERT INTO login VALUES ('TEST');
INSERT INTO login VALUES ('TEST2');
INSERT INTO business VALUES ('TEST','PASSWORD123');
INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('TEST2','PASSWORD1234');
```

I think you may solve the problem with the following query. Let's test with the user named "TEST2":

```
SELECT b.username AS business_user, c.username AS customer_user 
FROM login l
LEFT JOIN business b ON b.username = l.username
LEFT JOIN customer c ON c.username = l.username
WHERE l.username = 'TEST2' AND (b.password = 'PASSWORD1234' OR c.password = 'PASSWORD1234');
```

This query will return 2 columns as you notice: first one will return null as the user is not in business table. The second one will give you the username and label it as "customer_user". Therefore, if you check each column and determine which one is null, then you will know where the user actually belongs to (either to business or customer table).

The trick here is to begin with login table ("FROM login") and use LEFT JOIN, instead of JOIN. Here is a quick tip about joins and their differences, if you need it: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq93/